# How to get original login name while in Python CGI Apache web server?

Tags: python, apache

In Python CGI, when I call name = os.popen('whoami').read(), the name will return as Apache. How can I get the original login name that was login to this machine? For example, in terminal windows, when I run whoami, the login name return as "operator". In Apache server, is there a way to get the login name as "operator"?

Thanks!
Tom Wang

Comment: I am using the VNC client on my host server. I like to know if there is a way to tell that I am in VNC view. I checked os.environ.items(), they are all the same value when I run CGI on VNC server and VNC client. Basically when running on Apache, I can't tell if I am running on VNC server or client. Do you know if there is way to figure out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python CGI script gets executed when APACHE gets a request. APACHE redirects the request to python. Since, user 'APACHE' would be running this script, you get that as the id. You can only get the id as operator if user 'operator' is running the script. Users connect to your script using a web browser which is intercepted by APACHE. There is no way to determine which user is making the request from web browser as they never login to the machine where APACHE is running. You can get their IP/port using the requests library

Comment: What do you mean by " You can get their IP/port using the requests library"? Using this way to get the original login name?

Comment: You cannot get the original login as the user requesting the web page never logs in. You can find his IP like this - `cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])`

Comment: I am using the VNC client on my host server. I like to know if there is a way to tell that I am in VNC view. I checked os.environ.items(), they are all the same value when I run CGI on VNC server and VNC client. Basically when running on Apache, I can't tell if I am running on VNC server or client. Do you know if there is way to figure out? Thanks!